# Transform TextFormField to a printed format paper

Tags: flutter

I'm looking for a way that I can make a form in Flutter be printed with a button or just to be saved as a PDF and print it manually.

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply design the page you want to print using the PDF package's components, then pass the values you get from the TextFromFields to the page you want to print

It's better to add the PDF package https://pub.dev/packages/pdf/install  separately with the printing package https://pub.dev/packages/printing

Here is an example

```
    import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;
import 'package:printing/printing.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  runApp(const MyApp(['Value Form textFormField 1','Value Form textFormField 2']));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp(this.valuesFormTextFormFields, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final List<String> valuesFormTextFormFields;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Printing Demo')),
        body: PdfPreview(
          build: (format) => _generatePdf(format, valuesFormTextFormFields),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<Uint8List> _generatePdf(
      PdfPageFormat format, List<String> valuesFormTextFormFields) async {
    final pdf = pw.Document(version: PdfVersion.pdf_1_5, compress: true);

    pdf.addPage(
      pw.Page(
        pageFormat: format,
        build: (context) {
          return pw.Column(
            children: [
              pw.SizedBox(
                width: double.infinity,
                child: pw.FittedBox(
                    child: pw.Row(
                        children: valuesFormTextFormFields
                            .map((value) => pw.Text(value))
                            .toList())),
              ),
              pw.SizedBox(height: 20),
              pw.Flexible(child: pw.FlutterLogo())
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
    return pdf.save();
  }
}
```